# Search realtime with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, livesearch

I want to make a realtime search using jquery and a little vanilla javascript, I tried the code below :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type to search">
<button type="button" onclick="searchKey()">Serch</button>
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Grapes</td>
      <td>Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JAVACRIPT**

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
function searchKey()
{
    var val = $.trim($('#myInput').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    
    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $('#myInput').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
}
```

but instead the contents in the table disappear and don't work, but when I'm empty, then click submit again, the contents appear again, I want to fit the search, for example "p" comes out the contents that have the letter "p" when I click the submit button. and I want when I delete the search input, all the contents in the table immediately appear again without clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide and show the element if the text is present in the `td` using by adding/removing the CSS class `hide`

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

function searchKey() {
  var val = $.trim($('#myInput').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
  
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const elements = [...row.children];
    if (!elements.some(el => el.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(val)))
      row.classList.add("hide");
    else row.classList.remove("hide");
  })
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type to search">
<button type="button" onclick="searchKey()">Search</button>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want when I delete the search input, all the contents in the table immediately appear again without clicking the submit button.

You can define an `input` listener for your input tag. If the Content is empty, run the `searchKey` method.

```
$('#myInput').on('input', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.value.length)
    searchKey();
});
```

The full code will be:

```js
var $rows = $('#table tr');

$('#myInput').on('input', function(e) {
  if(!e.target.value.length)
    searchKey();
});

function searchKey() {
  var val = $.trim($('#myInput').val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $('#myInput').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type to search">
<button type="button" onclick="searchKey()">Serch</button>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Grapes</td>
    <td>Green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```